# Discord.js Lock Command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Working on a command that will lock a discord channel for a specific user:

Currently have:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    message.delete().catch(O_o=>{}); 
    if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Management", "Admin", "Helper"].includes(r.name))) return message.channel.send(`Invalid Permission!`)

    function closeDownChannel(message) {
        let channel = message.channel;
        let roles = message.guild.roles; 

        let testRole = roles.find('Customs Host');

        channel.overwritePermissions(
            testRole,
            { 'SEND_MESSAGES': false },
            'Competitive has Ended'
        )
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.log);
    }
}


module.exports.help = {
  name: "comp"
}
```

I have tried replacing "Customs Host" with the ID for the role, and still nothing. Also have done

> let testrole = (!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Custom Host"].includes(r.name)))

But still get no result with no error.

Run with command handler, every other command loads fine. Not trying to lock a channel for @everyone, just for the specific role.

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot to execute the function `closeDownChannel(message);`